# Как перейти к следующей итерации цикла из switch?

Tags: c++

`switch` находится в цикле, по определённому условию мне нужно применить `continue` к циклу, но компилятор применяет его к свичу. Как быть?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

По-моему вы говорите неправду. continue применяется именно к циклу.
Если попытаться написать continue в switch-е вне цикла, мой компилятор выдает: "error: continue statement not within a loop".

Comment: ой я наверно я путаю с php,  значит в моём коде баг в другом месте, а не в свиче... хотя визуально кажется что в нём.... ок спасибо =)

Answer (score 1):

В цикле сделай переменную bool если в свиче твое требование удовлетворено 1, и continue если нет то 0, потом как выйдешь из свича, в цикле еще, сделай условие if( переменная==1)
continue;

Answer (score 1):

Вы, вероятно, спутали с break - он действительно в данном случае будет применен к switch. А continue к switch не может быть примененим, поскольку является цикловым оперетором.

Comment: вот не понимаю зачем вы повторяете ответы, которые явно ничем не отличаются от тех что дали до вас?

Comment: Я уточняю и дополняю ответ другого. Имею на это право?